# python scrapy 302 (I want to back the original page)

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am gonna to scrape 
https://movie.douban.com/subject/1292052/ this page

but the url redirect to 
http://m.douban.com/movie/subject/1292052
  how  did I back to the first page and use the first page's parse way(xpath) to go on?
thanks!

Comment: how to up it to he top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are being redirected to the mobile site is because your user agent is not a known desktop browser.

You can modify `USER_AGENT` variable in `settings.py` to something like `USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'`

If you insist on not getting redirected, you can add `meta` variable in your request with `{'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]}`. This way, you won't get redirected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but if I use the second way then I can't event get the page(),view resopnse is a text which inform me to request the redirecting url.And the first way to use a User-Agent,yes,                                            
I did use a User-Agent'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Mobile Safari/537.36'            
Is it a mobile user-agent? I don't know how to change it ,but my way to get the user-agent is "responsive" in chrome .
I have been try to "iphone6"

Comment: so how to change the responsive way in chrome to get a nonmobile user-agent?

Comment: @TomJhonson-FFT You can get common user-agent strings from here: https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/